# Getting a 404 when accessing a servlet on JSP page form submit

Tags: jsp, servlets, http-status-code-404

I am getting a 404 when I submit a form from JSP which calls a servlet. Can someone please point out what's wrong here? I am sure I have missed something here

My JSP code

```
<form action="objectServer" method="get">
<select name="choice">

    <option value="1" %>1</option>
    <option value="2" %>2</option>
    <option value="3" %>3</option>



</select>
<br />
<input type="submit" value="View the Descrition!" />
```

My Servlet code

```
public class InfoServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
response)
 */
 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
 response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
    String selected = request.getParameter("choice");
    TestService service = new TestService();
    boolean redirector = service.redirect(selected);
    if(redirector){
        response.sendRedirect("next_page.jsp");
    } else {
        response.sendRedirect("this_page.jsp");
    }
 }
}
```

WEB.XML

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>InfoServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.storyapp.servlet.InfoServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>InfoServlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/objectServer</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Can you include the actual path which your form is attempting to hit?  404 means not found, which most likely means that the path to the servlet is wrong, and is not being caught by your `web.xml` file.  You may try to get the path right directly from your browser's location bar.

Comment: Can you include the actual path which your form is attempting to hit?

Comment: Do you mean including absolute path in my form action rather than relative path?

Comment: Figure out how to hit that servlet, then use that info in your form.

Comment: Oops, my JSP was hitting another-web-app/objectServer rather than my-web-app/objectServer. Corrected and it is working.   Thanks Tim

Comment: Yeah...I was expecting something like that.  Anyway, your setup is easy to debug, because you can just go into the browser's address bar and play around until you get it right.